# GMail compose on Firefox on Mac cmd+leftarrow cmd+rightarrow

Tags: macos, mac, gmail, firefox

I am using GMail and I cannot move to Firefox from Chrome, because the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> do not work in Compose window as "Move to the beginning of the line" and "Move to the end of the line", respectively.

How can I fix that?

(Mountain Lion 10.8.3, Firefox 20.0)

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally found a nice solution for this. I just started using [textbox.io](https://textbox.io/) for Firefox and the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> work like a charm.